# Match just the result of a capture group with regex?

Tags: regex

Basically I want to search for something and get a capture group, then ignore the search and get results that match that capture group.

So if I have this text:

```
apples are good
bananas are bad
oranges are good

I want oranges
I want bananas
I want apples
```

I'd want to search `(\w+) are good`, and then search `I want \1` to get 
`I want apples` and `I want oranges`.

How would I do this in one expression?

(sorry for the poor explanation)

Comment: Something like [(\w+) are good.*(I want \1)](https://regex101.com/r/FKaFiE/1) ?

Comment: What language are you using? Do you have a sample of what you have tried (such as doing it with two expressions)?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/Dc2nOw/1

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
/.*?(\w+?)\sare\sgood.*?(\w+?)\sare\sgood.*(I\swant\s(\1|\2)).*(I\swant\s(\1|\2))/s
```

It's a bit hacky since it will only work on the provided text, as far as I know there isn't a way to grab all occurrences of 'I want' for each occurrence of 'are good' using a single regex.